# Linking LAPACKE and Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, lapacke

I am new to C++ and I am using Eclipse to write a script. My OS is Ubuntu. I need to use the LAPACKE package partially for my code. I however cannot manage to link Eclipse and LAPACKE. I am trying to compile the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
double a[5][3] = {1,1,1,2,3,4,3,5,2,4,2,5,5,4,3};
double b[5][2] = {-10,-3,12,14,14,12,16,16,18,16};
lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
int i,j;

m = 5;
n = 3;
nrhs = 2;
lda = 3;
ldb = 2;

info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*b,ldb);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
   {
      printf("%lf ",b[i][j]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
return(info);
}
```

I am unable to compile the code as my Eclipse throws the error: "Udefined reference to LAPACKE_dgels". I have tried to link Eclipse to LAPACKE, for which I have added the path to LAPACKE header files in the "Paths and Symbols" tab of Eclipse. Can anyone help with what I need to do in order to resolve this issue? I should be missing something ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using gcc compiler. I guess you are missing `-llapack` flag in the compile arguments. If it doesn't work, try `-llapacke`. This flag (`-l[LibraryName]`) tells linker to use external binaries (see: [gcc: Difference between -L and -l option AND how to provide complete path to a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468211/gcc-difference-between-l-and-l-option-and-how-to-provide-complete-path-to-a-l)).

Check out this question to see how to add compiler flags in Eclipse: [How to add compiler options in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371215/how-to-add-compiler-options-in-eclipse-ide)