# How to add -lstdc++fs in Eclipse C++ for filesystem?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Here is a demo `filesystem-testing.cpp` on `c++` `filesystem` that works in command lines:

env: `gcc/5.5.0`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::string path = std::experimental::filesystem::current_path();

    std::cout << "path = " << path << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the compiling and testing:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 filesystem-testing.cpp -lstdc++fs
$ ./a.out
path = /home/userid/projects-c++/filesystem-testing
```

How to add `-lstdc++fs` in `Eclipse` `GCC C++ Compiler` and /or `GCC C++ Linker`?

The following ways didn't work and had `undefined reference` to `'_ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v112current_pathB5cxx11Ev'`

**1. Case A**

[image]

**2. Case B**

[image]

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371215/how-to-add-compiler-options-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: @NathanOliver the mentioned way didn't work as the updated information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example command line you gave creates an executable file from a source file in a single command, but it's typically done in two steps:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 filesystem-testing.cpp  # creates filesystem-testing.o
g++ filesystem-testing.o -lstdc++fs       # creates a.out
```

The first step invokes the compiler, the second step the linker (`g++` is the driver for both).

Note that the `-lstdc++fs` flag belongs to the linker command, not the compiler command.

Eclipse's managed build system also performs the compilation in these two steps. Accordingly, you need to specify `-lstdc++fs` in the linker options (e.g. `Tool Settings | GCC C++ Linker | Linker flags`).

---

**UPDATE**: OK, I tried this, and I see that adding the flag to `Linker flags` is not sufficient.

To understand why, let's look at the output in the Console view:

```
23:13:04 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o test.o ../test.cpp 
g++ -lstdc++fs -o test test.o 
test.o: In function `main':
/home/nr/dev/projects/c++/test/Debug/../test.cpp:7: undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::current_path[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

23:13:05 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 880ms)
```

Notice it shows you the commands it's running. The linker command it's running is:

```
g++ -lstdc++fs -o test test.o
```

This is different from what I wrote above in one important way: the `-lstdc++fs` options is before the input file that requires it (`test.o`), rather than after. [Order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/141719) for the GCC linker.

To fix this, we need to get Eclipse to change the order of arguments to the build system. You can do this by modifying `Tool Settings | GCC C++ Linker | Expert settings | Command line pattern`. This is basically a pattern for how Eclipse constructs the linker command line. Its default value is:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

Notice how `${FLAGS}` (which is where the `-lstdc++fs` goes) comes before `${INPUTS}` (which is where the `test.o` goes).

Let's reorder that to be:

```
${COMMAND} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} ${FLAGS}
```

And try building again:

```
23:20:26 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o test test.o -lstdc++fs 

23:20:26 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 272ms)
```

All is well now!

**UPDATE 2: The following worked as that highlighted in the snapshot.** It's important not to add `-l`:

[image]

Comment: @caot: The solution mentioned in "UPDATE 2" is a different approach: you are adding it to the `Libraries` list, so you don't want the `-l` prefix because that gets added automatically for library. I was suggesting putting it in `Linker flags` where you need the `-l`.

Comment: It didn't work to put it in Linker flags for Eclipse Invoking: GCC C++ Linker as `g++ -lstdc++fs -o ...`. The only way that works is `-lstdc++fs` located at the very end as the for mat of `g++ -o ... -o ...  -lstdc++fs`

Comment: @caot: Did you read the "UPDATE" section of my answer that talks about moving the flags in the `Command line pattern`?