# gcc: Difference between -L and -l option AND how to provide complete path to a library

Tags: g++

I am new to makefile stuff; so, please accept my apology if my questions are trivials.

**Question 1**: What is the difference between `-L` and `-l` option.

**Question 2**: How do you provide complete path to some library? For instance, "libeng" and "libmx", mentioned in following makefile,are located at {MATLABROOT}/bin/glnxa64

```
# root directory of MATLAB installation
MATLABROOT="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b"

all: engdemo

engdemo:
    g++ ${MATLABROOT}/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp -o engdemo \
        -I${MATLABROOT}/extern/include \
        -L${MATLABROOT}/extern/lib -llibeng -llibmx

clean:
    rm -f engdemo *.o
```

Update:
Following makefile works:

```
# root directory of MATLAB installation
MATLABROOT="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b"

all: engdemo

engdemo:
    g++ ${MATLABROOT}/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp -o engdemo \
        -I${MATLABROOT}/extern/include \
        #-L${MATLABROOT}/extern/lib -llibeng -llibmx
    -L${MATLABROOT}/bin/glnxa64 -llibeng \
    -L${MATLABROOT}/bin/glnxa64 -llibmx

clean:
rm -f engdemo *.o
```

I found following link about linking libraries very useful:
[http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html)

Comment: These are GCC options, not Make options.  You can learn about them by reading the manual.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks. I was able to modify.

Comment: You do not normally include the 'lib' part of the filename after the `-l` option. So for example `-llibmx` is usually writeen `-lmx`. I am surprised that the former works at all.

Answer (score 24):

Your question is refering to `gcc` linker (or simply `ld`).
Description can be found in in `gcc`'s [Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) or `ld`'s [Command Line Options](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html).

From the documentation you get

> `-larchive`:
> Add archive file `archive` to the list of files to link. `ld` will search its path-list for occurrences of `libarchive.a` for every archive specified.

> `-Lsearchdir`:
> Add path `searchdir` to the list of paths that `ld` will search for archive libraries and `ld` control scripts.

In your example you need to use `-L` to define the path where `libeng` and `libmx` libraries are located. Then use `-l` option to instruct `ld` to use these libraries.

Note that in the documentation is noted that:

> `ld` will search its path-list for occurrences of lib**archive**.a for every **archive** specified.