# Rust cdylib crate, linking dll to C program in Windows

Tags: c, gcc, rust

I have been trying to compile a simple rust `cdylib` crate in windows and linking it with a simple c program. Despite all my efforts I fail to link the `dll` file.

**Minimal example**

First of all my `rustc` version is:

```
C:\Users\User> rustc --version
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
```

I have a basic `Cargo.toml` which includes a `cbindgen` and sets the crate type:

```
[package]
name = "mycrate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["PauMAVA <--REDACTED-->"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "mycrate"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[build-dependencies]
cbindgen = "0.18.0"
```

Then the `lib.rs` only declares a really simple extern hello world function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn test_fn() {
    println!("Hello world from Rust!")
}
```

Finally, I generate the header file via `cdbindgen` in `build.rs`:

```rust
extern crate cbindgen;

use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use cbindgen::{Config, Builder};

fn main() {
    let crate_env = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
    let crate_path = Path::new(&crate_env);
    let config = Config::from_root_or_default(crate_path);
    Builder::new().with_crate(crate_path.to_str().unwrap())
        .with_config(config)
        .generate()
        .expect("Cannot generate header file!")
        .write_to_file("testprogram/headers/mycrate.h");
}
```

The generated header is the following:

```c
/* Generated with cbindgen:0.18.0 */

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test_fn(void);
```

The C code I have is the following simple program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "headers/mycrate.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello world from C!\n");
    test_fn();
}
```

Just to clarify, my file structure is the following:

```
testprogram
|-- headers
|    |-- mycrate.h
|
|-- main.c
|-- mycrate.dll
```

When I try to compile and link I get a linker error:

```
C:\Users\User\...\testprogram> gcc .\main.c -L.\mycrate.dll -o .\main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Pau\AppData\Local\Temp\cccQGbDk.o:main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `test_fn'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Additional Information**

The weird thing is that when compiling in WSL (Linux) I get a `.so` Linux library that just links correctly:

```
$ gcc main.c -L./mycrate.so -o main
$ ./main
Hello world from C!
Hello world from Rust!
```

What am I missing here? I guess this is merely a linking issue but I can't find the source of it. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have also tried using an absolute path when linking.
I am currently using `MinGW`.

**EDIT 2**

Also tried linking with the include library `mycrate.dll.lib` generated by cargo:

```
C:\Users\User\...\testprogram> gcc .\main.c -L.\mycrate.dll.lib -o .\main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Pau\AppData\Local\Temp\ccL0sH7B.o:main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `test_fn'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `rustc --version --verbose` output is:

```
C:\Users\User\...\testprogram> rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b
commit-date: 2021-02-10
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.50.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `gcc .\main.c -l.\mycrate.dll -o .\main`? [`-L` and `-l` are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468211/gcc-difference-between-l-and-l-option-and-how-to-provide-complete-path-to-a-l)

Comment: Tried with `-l` but I have the same error. If I'm not wrong `-L` is to specify the path of the lib while `-l` will search in the `PATH` for the library. Also tried using an absolute path with no luck.

Comment: Do you use Rust with MinGW or MSVC?

Comment: I am compiling using `MinGW`.

Comment: I see, that you compile your C program using MinGW, my question is what toolchain your Rust Compiler uses? You can check it using `rustc --version --verbose`. Maybe that's what you meant to say, but it does not quite sound like it.

Comment: On Linux programs are linked directly with the library (the `.so` file is used both at build time and at run time). On Windows the `.dll` file is only used at run time and you should link with an "import library" (with the `.lib` extension).

Comment: I have edited the question with the output of `rustc --version --verbose` and it seems that rust is working with `MSVC`. I have also tried to link with the import library as suggested by @Jmb with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are multiple problems here.

1. You compile the library for a 64bit system (because Rust is `x86_64`), but you try to link it with 32bit `MinGW`
2. Rust is using the `MSVC` toolchain and you try to compile the C program with `MinGW`
3. I am not entirely sure about that, but I think you linked the `mycrate.dll.lib` incorrectly. According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17209507/4593433) you should prefix it with `l` like so: `-L -lmycrate.dll.lib`

Obviously there are multiple ways to fix that. For example you can install Rust, so that it uses the `MinGW` toolchain as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380501/4593433).

Or you can use Visual Studio to compile your C code. That is what I did, because I did not want to bother with reinstalling Rust (Please correct me if am wrong, but I think there is no easy way to configure both `MSVC` and `MinGW` backends, so that one can switch easily between them in Rust).

The steps to compile and link with VisualStudio 2019 are as follows:

1. Build the Rust project `cargo build --release` with your 64 bit Rust installation using MSVC
2. Create a new `Empty C++` project
3. Add `main.c` and insert your code
4. In the same directory where your solution file is placed put `headers/mycrate.h`
5. Copy `mycrate.dll` and `mycrate.dll.lib` into the same directory where your *Solution* file is placed
6. Right click the C++ project in VisualStudio and select **Properties**
7. Select `Configuration=Release` and `Platform=x64`
8. Add `$(SolutionDir)\headers;` to `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`
9. Add `$(SolutionDir)mycrate.dll.lib;` to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`
10. **Apply** all changes and close the properties pane
11. Build the project in `Release` mode with the `x64` platform

If you build the Rust project in debug mode (e.g. `cargo build`) you will have to do the same for `Debug` mode.

I know it is kind of a convoluted process, so let me know if I should make Repo that serves as a demo for that process...

As I said, if you like to build using `MinGW`, you will have to setup Rust differently as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380501/4593433).

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. Making an example repo with an example project and this process explained in the README would be great as this information is nowhere to be found in the docs. Thank you again for your great response!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I think the reason why this is not documented anywhere on the Rust side is because there are so many different build systems and they all work differently. Getting this to work requires some VS specific knowledge, but it really depends on which platform you use to communicate with the rust code...
And then you need to make sure, that you compile the Rust code in a way that is compatible.